# Is it possible to set a timeout on openssl's s_client command?

Tags: unix, openssl, shell-scripting

I've got a script which uses openssl's s_client command to pull certificates for a big set of hosts.  Some of these hosts will inevitably be unreachable because of a firewall.  Is it possible to set the s_client timeout to something much shorter than the default?  I don't see one in the man page/help file.

That or some sort of wrapper command that will auto-kill the openssl -s_client after X number of seconds.

I'd prefer not to pre-test a host/port for usability if possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the timeout command from GNU coreutils package.

```
timeout <time> <command>
```

Alternatively, take a look at the first response to [this archived blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120311095406/http://bashcurescancer.com/timeout-new-coreutils-command.html) for a bash-only answer.

Answer (score 2):

for the first loop: while read servername;do

timeout 2 bash -c "/dev/tcp/$servername/$Port" && echo Port open. || echo Port closed.

done

But the open ports is more dificult:
timeout 1 openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $servername:$Port